# Vector space of matrices $M$ that diagonalize some matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be some matrix from the matrix vector space $M_n$ of all
>   square matrices of order $n$ such that $A$ has $n$ distinct
>   eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \dots \lambda_n$ and let
>   $D$ be a diagonal matrix formed from the eigenvalues of $A$ i.e. $$ D
>  =\begin{bmatrix}
>      \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
>      0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
>      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>      0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & \lambda_n \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> Proove that  $$ U = \{ M \in M_n\ |\  AM=MD\} $$ forms a vector
>   subspace of $M_n$. Determine the dimension and one basis of this
>   vector space. Check whether some of the matrices in the base is
>   invertible and based on that, conclude whether said subspace has any
>   invertible matrices in it.

The tricky thing about this problem is that I try to solve it using the info i am not supposed to use. For example, I recognize matrix diagonalization here, but I cannot use it in any way because $M$ is not said to be invertible ( that's actually part of the problem ).

Each column of $MD$ will be scaled columns of $M$ ( scaled by the corresponding eigenvalue in $D$ ). Now my question is : *Is this info enough to state that columns of M must be eigenvectors of $A$.*

Since eigenvectors corresponding to each of the eigenvalues are linearly independent, it's safe to   state that $M$ has an inverse, which gives the answer to the final question.

However, I have no idea how to determine the basis ( nor dimension ) of such vector space. My reasoning so far is that if the column space of $M$ is the space of eigenvectors of $A$, then my intuition tells me that the basis for space $U$ would be $n$ matrices, so that each is a matrix with every element zero except the $i$-th column, which would be the eigenvectors of $A$ respectively.

From here, it's obvious that none of the base matrices are invertible, but matrices formed as  linear combinations with non-zero coefficients of all base matrices are invertible.

So to conclude:

1. Did i provide enough info to state that columns of $M$ are eigenvectors of $A$.
2. Is my statement about the basis of this space correct?
3. Is my assumption about invertible matrices from $U$ true?

Comment: An idea:Put $V=\{X\in M_n; XD=DX\}$. There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=D$. Show that $M\in U$ is equivalent to say that $P^{-1}M \in V$. Let $g$ the application $M\to P^{-1}M$. Show that $g$ is an linear isomorphism from $U$ on $V$. Now it remains to study $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the dimension question, the proof is straightforward:

- If $M,M'\in U$, then  $A(M+M')=AM+AM'=MD+M'D=(M+M')D$
- If $M\in U$ and $c\in \Bbb R$, then $A(cM)=cAM=cMD=(cM)D$
- $U\ne \emptyset$ because $0\in U$ (even if $A$ is not diagonalizable orhas eigenvalues different from $D$!)

We know that $A$ is similar to $D$, i.e., that for some invertible $B$, we have $B^{-1}AB=D$, i.e., $B\in U$ (which ansers another part of the question). Clearly, the possible such $B$ are precisely those having eigenvectors of the correct eigenvalues in the corresponding columns.

Now the tricky part:
Let $M\in U$. Then for $\epsilon$ small enough, $B+\epsilon M$ is still invertible and $\in U$. We conclude that the columns of $B+\epsilon M$ are still eigenvectors. This is only possible if the columns of $M$ are either eigenvectors or $0$ (in short: are elements of the corresponding eigenspace).
We conclude that $M\in U$ if and only if each row is an element of the corresponding eigenspace. As each of these is one-dimensional, $\dim U=n$ and a suitable basis consists of matirces having an eigenvector in one row and zeroes otherwise.